# Multiple swagger instances with single wildlfy deployment

Tags: jboss, swagger, wildfly

I am using wildfly for exposing my APIs and swagger for API documentation.

I am in a situation where I need to expose only some APIs to some people and other APIs to others.

How to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using MicroProfile OpenAPI (recently integrated in WildFly 19.0.0.Final) which allows you to filter your OpenAPI document.
https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-open-api-1.1.2/microprofile-openapi-spec.html#_filter